# How can I fix the error "The [standard] token filter has been removed"?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to upgrade a project from ElasticSearch 2.3 with NEST version 2.5.8 to ElasticSearch 7.9 with NEST 7.11.1. When I try to create the index I get the error:

`# OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.. Call: Status code 400 from: PUT /partsearch.01. ServerError: Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "failed to build synonyms" CausedBy: "Type: parse_exception Reason: "Invalid synonym rule at line 1" CausedBy: "Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "The [standard] token filter has been removed."""`

The code that is attempting to create the index when this error occurs is:

```
protected internal CreateIndexResponse CreateIndex(string name)
{
    var indicesOperationResponse = this.elasticClientProxy.CreateIndex(
        name, c => c
            .Settings(
                s => s
                    .NumberOfReplicas(this.numberOfReplicas)
                    .NumberOfShards(this.numberOfShards)
                    .Setting("index.max_result_window", this.maxResultWindow)
                    .Analysis(
                        ad => ad
                            .CharFilters(this.RegisterCharFilters)
                            .Tokenizers(this.RegisterTokenizers)
                            .TokenFilters(this.RegisterTokenFilters)
                            .Analyzers(this.RegisterAnalyzers)))
            .Map<T>(this.Map)
            .Map<IndexMetaData>(this.MapIndexMetaData));

    return indicesOperationResponse;
}
```

The implementation of the RegisterTokenFilters is:

```
protected internal override TokenFiltersDescriptor RegisterTokenFilters(TokenFiltersDescriptor descriptor)
{
    return descriptor.UserDefined(TokenFilter.NormalizeNumberSeparator.DisplayName, TokenFilter.NormalizeNumberSeparator.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.CustomStopWordFilter.DisplayName, TokenFilter.CustomStopWordFilter.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.StripNumberUnit.DisplayName, TokenFilter.StripNumberUnit.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.StripEndingPunctuation.DisplayName, TokenFilter.StripEndingPunctuation.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.StripCommaFromNumber.DisplayName, TokenFilter.StripCommaFromNumber.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.EnglishStemmer.DisplayName, TokenFilter.EnglishStemmer.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.EnglishPossessiveStemmer.DisplayName, TokenFilter.EnglishPossessiveStemmer.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.PatternFilter.DisplayName, TokenFilter.PatternFilter.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.SynonymFilter.DisplayName, TokenFilter.SynonymFilter.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.StripLeadingCharNoise.DisplayName, TokenFilter.StripLeadingCharNoise.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.NumericSynonymFilter.DisplayName, TokenFilter.NumericSynonymFilter.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.StemmerExclusionFilter.DisplayName, TokenFilter.StemmerExclusionFilter.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.AsciiFoldingTokenFilter.DisplayName, TokenFilter.AsciiFoldingTokenFilter.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.DashWordsSynonymFilter.DisplayName, TokenFilter.DashWordsSynonymFilter.Filter)
        .UserDefined(TokenFilter.DashSplitTokenFilter.DisplayName, TokenFilter.DashSplitTokenFilter.Filter);
}
```

I wanted to find and remove the Standard token filter based on answers I found to similar errors but I don't see it being used here.

How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Comment: Running the client in debug mode and capturing the request bytes might help to investigate: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-mode.html. Does one of the analyzers specify using `"standard"` token filter?

Comment: @RussCam Your question about the analyzers was the clue I needed. I reviewed the code inside the RegisterAnalyzers method and sure enough there were 2 places where it called for TokenFilter.Standard. I removed those and that error "The [standard] token filter has been removed" is now gone. Now I get the error "term: abb-vg analyzed to a token (abb) with position increment != 1 (got: 0)""". The first line in one of the synonym files is abbvg,abb-vg. But that's a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The method RegisterAnalyzers made a call that led to this code:

```
private static AnalyzerBase CustomDescriptionAnalyzer()
{
    var customAnalyzer = new CustomAnalyzer();

    customAnalyzer.CharFilter = new List<string>
        {
            CharacterFilter.HtmlStrip.DisplayName,
            CharacterFilter.UniCodeFilter.DisplayName
        };

    customAnalyzer.Tokenizer = Tokenizer.DescriptionTokenizer.DisplayName;
    
    customAnalyzer.Filter = new List<string>
        {
            TokenFilter.Standard.DisplayName, 
            TokenFilter.Lowercase.DisplayName,
            TokenFilter.StripLeadingCharNoise.DisplayName,  
            TokenFilter.PatternFilter.DisplayName,
            TokenFilter.StripLeadingCharNoise.DisplayName,
            TokenFilter.NormalizeNumberSeparator.DisplayName,
```

I removed the line `TokenFilter.Standard.DisplayName` from the `customerAnalyzer.Filter` list and now I don't get the error `Type: parse_exception Reason: "Invalid synonym rule at line 1" CausedBy: "Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "The [standard] token filter has been removed`

See also

- [Breaking changes in 7.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#standard-filter-removed)
- [The [standard] token filter has been removed #175](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/issues/175)
- [Standard token filter removal causes exceptions after upgrade #50734](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/50734)